# Redirect non-directory to a directory in apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I think this is a simple fix, but I just couldn't find correct words to search for my problem.

I want people visiting something like:

```
apps/example
```

to redirect to

```
apps/example/
```

Currently when I visit first url, it shows 404 error.

Comment: Mod Rewrite can handle things like this

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I tried RedirectMatch but it doesnt work properly. If you could specify the line to add to .htaccess file

Answer (score 1):

This should do it, I would have thought;

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^apps/example$ apps/example/ [L]
```

Comment: actually example i dont want specific redirection. I want in general anything after apps/ redirected that way

Comment: @ShashankJain then use `RewriteRule ^apps/(.*[^/])$ apps/$1/   [L]`